# Insert Issues using EF in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/ApexAdmin.Master"
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ApexTrackDays.Models.Event>" %>
 <% using (Html.BeginForm())
                   {%>
                <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
                 <tr><td>Experience level</td><td><div class="editor-field">
                    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExperienceLevelID, (SelectList)ViewData["Experience"], "--select--")%>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExperienceLevelID) %>
                </div></td></tr>

                <tr><td>No of Helmets</td><td><div class="editor-field">
              <%: Html.DropDownList("helmets", (SelectList)ViewData["size"], "--select--")%>
               </div></td></tr>

                 <tr><td>No of Garages</td><td><div class="editor-field">
              <%: Html.DropDownList("garages", (SelectList)ViewData["garages"], "--select--")%>
               </div></td></tr>


                [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Event trackday)
    {

        ViewBag.mode = "create";
         // for dropdown experience -- Inserts into Events table
        IExperienceLevelRepository expLevelResp = new ExperienceLevelRepository();
        IQueryable<ExperienceLevel> expLevel = expLevelResp.GetAllExperienceLevels().OrderBy(ExperienceLevel => ExperienceLevel.Name);
        ViewData["Experience"] = new SelectList(expLevel, "ID", "Name");

       // dropdown for helmets -- This should insert into Products table
        var helmets = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
        ViewData["helmets"] = new SelectList(helmets.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

        // dropdown for garages -- This should insert into Products table
        var garages = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
        ViewData["garages"] = new SelectList(garages.ToList(), "Value", "Text");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            trackday.DateAdded = DateTime.Now; //Inserts Date into Events table
            trackday.DateModified = DateTime.Now; //Inserts Date into Events table
            trackdayResp.Add(trackday);
            trackdayResp.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Hi , I have got one to many relationship with Events(1):Products(*)[1event can have different products Available] , but when inserting data using EF , it only inserts into Event table , it doesnt cascade the insertion with product table , any ideas or any help will be highly appreciated . thanx

Comment: Did you check in the debugger that `trackday` actually contains a collection of products when you call `trackdayResp.Add(trackday)`? And what do your comments "This should insert into Products table" mean? You are only creating SelectListItems, how is this supposed to insert anything into the DB?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the view for your products
Try adding  a line

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model=>mode.Products) %>
```

which will render an editor for your products - but you probably want to tailor it by creating a Products.ascx in EditorTemplates

hope this helps.